# will claims changes trigger an onIdTokenChanged

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#on-idtoken-changed) says that this function

> Adds an observer for changes to the signed-in user's ID token, which includes sign-in, sign-out, and token refresh events.

My question, is does this mean any changes to the id token, including changes to the claims, or only signin, signout, and token refresh?

My use case is that I want to push authorization changes, if they lose some privilege, they should be immediately barred from newly prohibited resources, not just on next load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it includes changes to custom claims for that account.  The problem is that you can't really "force" a push of claims updates.  The client app must willingly get a new ID token, and a compromised app might choose not to do that.  At least that effect will last no more than 1 hour, until the current ID token expires and must be refresh.  But you can still wire up your app to refresh the token in response to a message or some other update.

Comment: so basically the answer is "No", since change of claims does NOT activate onRetrieveToken, but a token refresh does.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "onRetrieveToken".  If you mean the listener for ID token changes, that listener does not immediate fire when custom claims are changed, but when it does, it will have updated claims in it.

Comment: sorry, I meant 'onIdTokenChanged'

Comment: I downvoted this because your answer is misleading. The answer will be better rephrased to "NO, `setCustomUserClaims()` will NOT trigger `onIdTokenChanged`. You will have to manually update and listen to another custom document stored either on Firestore or Realtime Database for ID token re-fetch trigger."

Comment: @IvanWang Strictly speaking, the client does not have to manually update.  The token will update automatically by the within an hour of the last refresh.  At that point, onIdTokenChanged will trigger with the update.  If you can point to documentation that suggests differently, I will update the answer.  Otherwise, please consider adding your own answer that you think is more correct.

Comment: @DougStevenson firstly OP's question is if custom claim updates will trigger `onIdTokenChanged`, not asking if it's a good idea to check if claims are updated. Secondly, there is definitely value in revalidating the token immediately after claims update. Depends on use cases, 1 hour could be a significant amount of time that the client's permissions went out of sync. I think your answer has the correct information, just the conclusion is somehow ambiguous.

Comment: @IvanWang I'm very aware of the fact that it's sometimes desirable to get an fast reload of custom claims.  [I wrote a whole blog post about it](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-supercharged-custom-claims-with-firestore-and-cloud-functions-bb8f46b24e11).  The client has to refresh to get a fast update, and that was stated in the answer when I said "you can still wire up your app to refresh the token in response to a message or some other update."

Comment: @DougStevenson is there a reason why `onIdTokenChanged` _isn't_ triggered when custom claims are updated?  That seems like an incredibly obvious behavior.  The API documentation even states "When there is a change in the current user's token" as a trigger condition, and altering custom claims is certainly a change to the current user's token.

Comment: @bsplosion New tokens aren't pushed to the client.  The client has to pull a new token periodically, and that's what triggers the callback.  The client has no way of knowing if something on the backend changes without checking.

Comment: @DougStevenson I think that's what everyone has found surprising about the `onIdTokenChanged` behavior.  It looks and seems to act like a hook for the ID token state on the auth platform itself, but in reality it only seems to be against the internal ID token state within the client.  It'd be great to have an option that listens for the auth state on the platform, much like `onSnapshot` functions for Firestore.  Having live auth status is vitally important for many applications and it's surprising we have to roll our own solution with Firebase Auth.

Comment: @bsplosion If you have a feature request, contact Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact